# Unit testing sessions is still returning null after Mocking

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, session, mocking, httpcontext

I am trying to write a unit test to test my controller which makes use of session. I understand the concept that the httpcontext is only generated from request which is from the browser and since calling a controller action form Unit test, the current context will be null.

I tried to solve this issue based on the first part of this article [http://www.dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2011/03/22/testing-session-in-mvc-in-four-lines-of-code/](http://this) but it still isn't working for me. See my code below.

```
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Configure_AutoMapper()
    {
        _product = new ProductViewModel()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Category = Guid.Parse("72E42A11-DFA4-4AB9-A735-5CD5C18396D4"),
            Brand = Guid.Parse("96E68B67-60FB-4531-898E-815433B44D89"),
            Description = "From test",
            CostPrice = Parse("17.00"),
            SalePrice = Parse("25.00"),
            Quantity = 7,
            BusinessId = Guid.Parse("BDF9FB7F-DB40-4365-9872-AECD616ED415")
        };

        var context = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        context.Setup(m => m.HttpContext.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        _productsController = new ProductsController {ControllerContext = context.Object};

        var userSessionInfo = new UserSessionViewModel()
        {
            FirstName = "Junior",
            LastName = "Labolz",
            BusinessId = Guid.Parse("BDF9FB7F-DB40-4365-9872-AECD616ED415")
        };

        SessionHelper.AddUserDetailsToSession(SessionHelper.UserDetails, userSessionInfo);
    }


    [Test]
    public void Display_Products_List_On_View_Products_Button_Click()
    {
        //Set Up

        //Act
        var viewResult = (ViewResult)_productsController.Index();

        //Assert
        Assert.That(string.Empty, Is.EqualTo(viewResult.ViewName));
    }


    public static void AddUserDetailsToSession(string sessionName, UserSessionViewModel userSessionDetails)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(sessionName, userSessionDetails);
    }
```

**Based on Richard's answer I changed it to **

```
        var context = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        context.Setup(m => m.HttpContext.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        var userSessionInfo = new UserSessionViewModel()
        {
            FirstName = "Junior",
            LastName = "Labolz",
            BusinessId = Guid.Parse("BDF9FB7F-DB40-4365-9872-AECD616ED415")
        };
        context.Object.HttpContext.AddUserDetailsToSession(SessionHelper.UserDetails, userSessionInfo);

        _productsController = new ProductsController {ControllerContext = context.Object};
```

**Product controller constructor**

```
    public ProductsController()
    {
        _productService = new ProductServiceClient();
        _userSessionViewModel = (UserSessionViewModel)SessionHelper.GetSessionDetail(SessionHelper.UserDetails);
    }
```

**Get Session method**

```
    public static object GetSessionDetail(string sessionName)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionName];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see your code contains a static function which references HttpContext.Current directly.  You cannot do this if you want to unit test, you must work with injected instances of HttpContextBase instead.

In your unit tests, these instances will be your mock context.  In production, you would set up your container to inject HttpContext.Current when HttpContextBase is requested.

I would rewrite your static method to be an extension method:

```
public static void AddUserDetailsToSession(this HttpContextBase context, 
    string sessionName, UserSessionViewModel userSessionDetails)
{
    context.Session.Add(sessionName, userSessionDetails);
}
```

Then call it from your test:

```
context.Object.AddUserDetailsToSession(SessionHelper.UserDetails, userSessionInfo);
```

Comment: I am still getting a null reference exception, maybe because I am also trying to read the session in my productController constructor ?

Comment: I have updated my code, please have a look for me. I changed it to use an extension method, I have a title in my update "based on Richard's answer". I am also showing you what i have in my product controller

Comment: You cannot use HttpContext.Current anywhere - you can get at HttpContext from the ControllerContext.  You shouldn't be accessing Session from the controller constructor anyway, as you don't have the context at the point this is called.

Comment: noted! thank you, in my controller I am now using                 var userSessionViewModel = (UserSessionViewModel)this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session[SessionHelper.UserDetails];  but that sets userSessionViewModel to null, but i think i am already setting my controller context session to a value in the test, why is it still returning null after i am trying to get the session from the controller context in my controller